# DDQN doesn't learn my modified version of Taxi-v3 from OpenAI

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl

I tried to enhance the Taxi-v3 environment from OpenAI (true credit goes of course to https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/9905014) to be capable of handling multiple taxis/passengers. Don't worry, I'm not starting with multi-agent RL for debugging, I decided for a simple 3x3 grid with one passenger, one taxi, and no borders.

Here is some random starting state:

```
+-----+ 
|A: : | 
|a:0: | 
| : : |
+-----+
```

`a` is the current location of a passenger, `A` its destination location, and `0` the location of the taxi. The taxi will get a positive reward when first picking up the passenger and then dropping him/her off at `A`; everything else is punished.

After spending quite some time debugging it, I decided to ask for help ... **my DDQN agent does not learn!**

You can find my code here: **https://github.com/SorenSc/multi-taxi-drl**

The DRL agent is build via the library [tianshou](https://tianshou.readthedocs.io/en/master/).

I tried various things:

- Try hyperparameter tuning (learning rate, gamma, ...)
- Looked at weights and biases (the network seems to learn something)
- Used logging (didn't see anything out of the ordinary)
- Tracked various metrics like the reward.

But even after 5000 epochs of training, the DRL agent selects the same action all the time. The action selected might vary with different start states, but it doesn't vary in one epoch.

**Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?**

My best guess is that I'm not seeing a bug in the environment...

Learning of a DDQN agent **in my environment (blue)** in comparison to one learned in the **original Taxi-v3 environment in orange**.
[image]

Weights/biases during training:
[image]